# componentDidUpdate is not triggered correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Good afternoon,

For the first time with React I have been stuck that much, cannot understand why componentDidUpdate does not give me correct results. What I am trying to do is to do some changes on child components depending on the incoming number of tags through props. And when I try logging all the changes happened in the component, you can clearly see that the number of tags have changed, but it does not log the cycle that it updated my component.

Here is my componentDidUpdate method:

```
  componentDidUpdate(previousProps) {
    if (this.props.message.id == 11553) {
      console.log(`Current tag array length: ${this.props.message.tags.length}, previous: ${previousProps.message.tags.length}`);
    }
  }
```

And here is the log result:

```
MessageTags.js:190 Current tag array length: 4, previous: 4
MessageTags.js:190 Current tag array length: 4, previous: 4
MessageTags.js:190 Current tag array length: 4, previous: 4
MessageTags.js:190 Current tag array length: 4, previous: 4
MessageTags.js:190 Current tag array length: 4, previous: 4
socket.js:41 SOCKET DATA RECEIVED -> createTag:  {…}
MessageTags.js:190 Current tag array length: 5, previous: 5
MessageTags.js:190 Current tag array length: 5, previous: 5
```

After socket response, a new tag is added into redux state. I have checked if the component is somehow re-rendered, so it does not update but directly be rendered, and it did not trigger componentDidMount() method again. So I believe it is not removed and re-rendered.

What would be the issue in my case here?

Comment: Can you include the method that updates `this.props.tags`?

Comment: Can you include the component and parent component?

Comment: @HenryWoody this.prop.tags item is extracted from a message object which is passed through Dashboard>Stream>Post>MessageTags. In this case, when we update the redux store after socket response, the tags are updated too. I do not call any method inside app which updates tags manually.

Comment: I assume that the messages or tags somewhere is mutated, may be during your redux update or so. And that would be reason. Please show your related reducer code..

Comment: by any change is your child component a pureComponent